# how to version_compare each array value in php?

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I have two arrays I need to compare with the operator `<=`. I thought an easy way to try and do this is using `version_compare` but I'm not sure that A. This is best method and B. It's actually comparing the right values.

In order for version_compare to work I implode the array.

```
//Original arrays.

a$ = array( 0 => "ajax dropdown0.1.5", 1 => "hello dolly1.6", 2 => "test4.5");
b$ = array( 0 => "ajax dropdown0.1.4", 1 => "hello dolly1.6", 2 => "test4.6");

//implode into string

$a_implode = implode( "," , $a );
$b_implode = implode( "," , $b );

//compare version

if (version_compare($a_implode, $b_implode, '<=')){
                    echo 'We have a problem';
                    }
```

This seems to work but I have no idea if it's actually comparing the correct values, for instance test4.5 must only be compared to test4.6 ( and not the other string values), also I am unsure how to output any matches if version_compare returns true.

Comment: Your imploded array wouldn't follow the PHP version numbering convention, so this function will NOT do what you want. You should compare the individual component versions separately.

Comment: I don't quite follow what you're trying to do here. What constitutes meeting the if condition? Is there a problem if any one doesn't satisfy the version comparison, or if all of them don't?

Comment: If $a is less then or equal to $b, return $a. Expect I know this is wrong since I have to compare each value in the array for text match and then compare version number.

Answer (score 2):

```
    foreach( array_keys( $a ) AS $key ) {            
        if( version_compare($a[$key], $b[$key], '<=')) { print "we have a problem with: " . $a[$key] . "\n"; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have made a simple Class for you to solve your problem as easy as its posibble.

the Class file (class.myversion.php)

```
<?php
class MyVersion
{
    private $_version;
    private $_name;

    public function __construct($_name, $_version)
    {
        $this->_version = $_version;
        $this->_name = $_name;
    }
    public function getVersion()
    {
        return $this->_version;
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->_name;
    }
}
?>
```

And the Test File (test.php)

```
require 'class.myversion.php';

$a = Array();
$b = Array();

$a[] = new MyVersion("ajax dropdown", 15); // 15 means 0.1.5
$a[] = new MyVersion("hello dolly", 16);
$a[] = new MyVersion("test", 45);

$b[] = new MyVersion("ajax dropdown", 14); // 14 means 0.1.4
$b[] = new MyVersion("hello dolly", 16);
$b[] = new MyVersion("test", 46);

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($a); $i++)
    if($a[$i]->getVersion() < $b[$i]->getVersion())
        echo "(".$a[$i]->getName().")needs to get Updated. Required version: ".$b[$i]->getVersion()."<br />";
    elseif($a[$i]->getVersion() > $b[$i]->getVersion())
        echo "(".$b[$i]->getName().")needs to get Updated. Required version: ".$a[$i]->getVersion()."<br />";
?>
```

Thats it! If you think its hard to understand, i can explain it but i think its easy enought to understand.

Comment: Ya sorry this is above my skill level, I get an error `Call to a member function getVersion() on a non-object`

Comment: You have to create the class file and call it with require function.